# Should/How would I use .slice() to swap an image scr on a button press? (for next/previous button use in a gallery)

Tags: javascript, image, split, slice, parseint

I am stumped and could really use some help with this gallery I've been working on. I used Ivan's '4 lines of jquery gallery' tutorial to get me where I am at currently. Here's his demo which shows exactly how it all works http://workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/

I've hit the point where I would like to include a previous and back button.

As the images are named '1-large.jpg','2-large.jpg','3-large.jpg'... etc I tried using the .slice() to take the first digit then add 1 or minus 1 to it, resulting in the next/previous pic but that didn't work well at all as my javascript skills are lacking and I don't even know if it's the best way to approach it.

My question is - Is using .slice() the way to go or is there a more simpler code I can use on my buttons?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the first character of a string:

```
var name = "1-large.jpg";
var i = name[0];
// i is now '1'
```

but this won't work for i > 9, so using split would be better:

```
var i = name.split('-')[0];
// i is now '1'

var i = "1023-large.jpg".split('-')[0];
// i is now '1023'
```

and to convert string to int:

```
var num = parseInt("23", 10);
// num is now the number 23, not a string
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sean. I updated what I had with the code you suggested but I've missed something when it comes to inserting the variable into the image url:  $('#arrow-right').click(function(){  var i = '#largeImage'.split('-')[0];  var i = i++;  $('#largeImage').attr('src', 'images/illustration/' + i + '-large.jpg');  });  
It seems to be returning a url 'images/illustration/NAN-large' which makes me think it's how I've inserted the variable....?

Comment: this: `var i = '#largeImage'.split('-')[0];` looks like it should be `var i = $('#largeImage').attr('src').split('-')[0];`. But to be sure output the value of `$('#largeImage').attr('src')` with `console.log($('#largeImage').attr('src'));`, hit F12 to see the console in Firefox or Chrome, and make sure it looks something like "1023-large.jpg"

Comment: I really appreciate the help Sean. Just tried it out and I get `images/illustration/NaN-large.jpg`. I completely missed the conversion parseInt step you mentioned so I included that in the script changing it to read `var i = parseInt(i, 10);` and put it directly after the `var i = i++` line. No luck.

Comment: YES! Got it! Because I was using the full image path like `images/illustration/1-large.jpg` when the `split('-')[0]` occurred it was leaving the whole front section `images/illustration/1`, which was leading to the NaN (I would wig out too if someone asked me to add 1 to NaN and expect a numerical value). So I changed it to `split('/')[2]` then used the parseInt to bring out the number. Once again, thanks for getting me on the right track Sean. Cheers.